# How to add a custom listener in CKEditor 4.8? editor.on is not a function

Tags: ckeditor, listener

I'm trying to follow the [guide of inserting a custom listener](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_file_upload.html#editor-side-configuration) for CKEDITOR using "editor.on", inserting into ckeditor.config.js but I get

> Uncaught TypeError: editor.on is not a function

I need this in order to change editor request & response to get JSON so that the uploadimage plugin can work. Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: I also tried "CKEDITOR.editor.on" and "CKEDITOR.on" which didn't give me any errors but it's not working :(

I even added "console.log("test here");" into the code to see if it's being triggered but no message appeared in the console.

CKEDITOR.on( 'fileUploadRequest', function( evt ) {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to load it in the ckeditor.config.js that worked for me, but if you know a better way or are aware of any implications please correct me, thanks.

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function( ev ) {
ev.editor.on // followed by the code
} );
```

example code for the guide above I used:

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function( ev ) {
ev.editor.on( 'fileUploadRequest', function( evt ) {
var xhr = evt.data.fileLoader.xhr;
xhr.setRequestHeader( 'Cache-Control', 'no-cache' );
xhr.setRequestHeader( 'X-CUSTOM', 'HEADER' );
xhr.withCredentials = true;
} );
```